# Why use spread operator in Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-media-library-with-react-redux-and-redux-saga-part-2), why is there a spread operator before `createStore`?

```
const configureStore = () => {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware(); 
  return {
    ...createStore(rootReducer,
      applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)),
    runSaga: sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)
  };
};
```

Comment: See http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html#using-object-spread-operator

Comment: Spread operator is useful so that you don't have to write all the properties of the object and assign the new state to each one of them. Spread operator will make it work out of the box. Later, you only specify the properties you want to persist the state for.

Comment: I know that the spread operator copies over the store, but why do you need to do that here? You don't need to copy the store, just create it. Does it have to something to do with how runSaga works? Looking at the docs, it doesn't seem like the store prop for `Provider` takes something called `runSaga`

Comment: But it needs to add the additional `runSaga` property. To do that you need to make a copy to hold the additional property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that that example is trying to add an additional field to the store object, so that you can call `store.runSaga()`.  To be honest, the spread/copy is totally unnecessary - you can just do `store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run`.

Comment: where in the tutorial does the author call `runSaga` though?

Comment: Doesn't look like the author actually uses that in the tutorial.

Comment: Then how does it work? Don't you have to call `runSaga` somewhere?

Comment: I didn't write the tutorial, so I'm not sure exactly what the author was thinking :)